# remote debugging windows 8.1 driver Visual studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging

I'm trying to set up remote debugging on Visual studio 2013.
I think I installed everything on my computer and the hyper-v machine too + updated.

So whats happening:
I open a microsoft UMDF driver sample. (I can build it without any errors).
I select Debugging tools for windows remote debugger.
Then a message box pops up named Deployment not configured.

I select I know what I'm doing continue debugging.
Then the Computer configuration wizard starts add new computer.
I select provision computer and automatically configure debuggers.
Then the configuration process configure my hyper-v machine fine.
Installs the necessary files restart the computer and log in with the name WDKRemoteUser.
Then I Click Finish then this error pop-up.

The required property 'DbgengRemoteCommand' is missing or empty. (OK)

So I need to fill up the package property pages->configuration properties->debugging->
Remote Command, Remote Command Arguments, Remote Working Directory, Remote Computer name manually?

And if I had to what should I write there or I miss something else?

Answer (score 0):

You only need to specify the "Remote Working Directory" parameter and you can just give it the same path as your build directory and you should be good.